# Angular5: where are "converters" ? (i.e. like JSF)

Tags: angular, converters

I'm trying to port a Jsf application to Angular5.
In Jsf there is a useful concept called converter. A converter is used to convert input component values (strings) to the correct data model type.
Is there something similar in Angular ?
Suppose I have a Date field

```
myfield: Date;
```

and an input component like this :

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="myfield">
```

I've not found an easy way to convert the value typed in the input component to a Date. 
The only solution I've found is to handle the ngDataChange event and manually parse/convert the string to a Date. (and apply a pipe to show the Date in the right format)

I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use date pipe in angular 4 to display date in format like `{{valueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}`

But it will not work as input field. I would you should convert that in your typescript.

Angular 5 is also javascript and javascript is loosely typed language. so what ever you see in the html page are considered as string. So in your typescript you can write a function to convert to date if it required.

I would say, in the html normally data are displayed so it does not matter its date or string but while sending it to the server or doing some operation in you call java script `Date()`

Comment: Angular uses typescript, a strongly typed language! If I use a typed field ( <> any) I'm expecting the framework give me a way to convert the value in the right type.